# Using Chakra UI Select component in react app - it keeps on showing place holder but value is being updated

Tags: reactjs, drop-down-menu, react-typescript, chakra-ui

i have the following code:

```
<Select 
    placeholder='Bet Size'
    onChange={handleWhichBetSize}
>
    <option value={BetSizes.Solana01}>0.1 SOL</option>
    <option value={BetSizes.Solana05}>0.5 SOL</option>
    <option value={BetSizes.Solana1}>1.0 SOL</option>
</Select>
```

Where handleWhichBetSize is defined as:

```
const [bet_size, setBetSize] = useState<number>(0);
const handleWhichBetSize = (event : React.ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement>) => {console.log("event: ", event.target.value); setBetSize(parseInt(event.target.value));};
```

This correctly initially shows the place holder, and when i first select an option, it will display that, however if i then select something different it shows the place holder again.  Note that the actual value bid_size is being updated behind the scenes, (the log statement is being printed, and i can access the updated value in other functions) it is just the front end is showing the place holder incorrectly.

I need to select new options twice to get them to show up on the component GUI.  ie:

```
Initial state - shows place holder
Select 0.1 SOL - shows 0.1 SOL
Select 0.5 SOL - shows place holder
Select 0.5 SOL - shows 0.5 SOL
Select 0.1 SOL - shows place holder
Select 0.1 SOL - shows 0.1 SOL
etc
```

If i just cycle through options without selecting twice i get:

```
Initial state - shows place holder
Select 0.1 SOL - shows 0.1 SOL
Select 0.5 SOL - shows place holder
Select 0.1 SOL - shows place holder
etc
```

What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: It will be useful to also see the other part of the code where the ChakraUI and your state is being used.